# What's the definition of 'outcomes' in the textbook?

Tags: probability

I'm reading the book *Discrete Mathematics and It's Application, Rosen, 7th ed.*, at page 446

[image: The pic. of def. using the word 'outcome']

Say there are 5 balls, 3 black 2 white, then if an experiment is defined as taking out 1 ball from those, then should the sample space be

$$\{B_1,B_2,B_3,W_1,W_2\}$$

or just

$$\{B,W\}$$

?

Comment: Do you notice that you said *taking out 1 ball from those* without specifying what you want to observe? Yeah, you didn't have a target at that moment boi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is okay, depending on *why* you want to use them.

The sample space  $\{B_1,B_2,B_3,W_1,W_2\}$ has the advantage that it lists *equiprobable* outcomes.   This may be helpful in explaining how probability masses for the events are evaluated, since it will be just a ratio of counts of outcomes (favoured over total).

The sample space $\{B, W\}$ has the advantage that it only lists *distinguishable* outcomes.   This makes writting expressions about the events of interest somewhat self-commenting and easier to typeset.   However, you will also need to explain the probabilty measure for each outcome as they do have different weightings.

---

In any case, $\mathsf P\{B\}=\mathsf P\{B_1,B_2,B_3\} = 3/5\\\mathsf P\{W\}=\mathsf P\{W_1,W_2\} = 2/5$.